# Can a task in build.gradle depend on a task in a plugin

Tags: gradle

Is there any way to make a task in the projects's `build.gradle` depend on a task which is in a plugin that is applied to this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. See the example below:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task lol << {
    println "LOL"
}

compileJava.dependsOn lol
```

Comment: @sver, it is also possible, but only in one direction. Otherwise you'll get circular dependency.